# C not returning

Tags: c, gcc, codelite

I have downloaded Codelite IDE for C and when I run my code I don't receive anything.
this is what I receive: [This is what I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1DI6.png)

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I just ran the code and I was expecting the code to print out hello world

Comment: Strictly speaking, `int main()` is not a valid signature for `main`. I don't actually expect that to be a problem, though. This program is fine - something else is wrong with your setup.

Comment: You should not post images of text, just put the text in your post so it can be searched/copied.  Sinec your code is fine, you probably need to search for things like "Codelite error 32766" and also put your operating system in the search query.

Comment: My guess is that you have a directory with an incompatible DLL for the runtime earlier in your path than the mingw directory. Rearranging the path may help this issue but break something else.

Comment: `int main()` should be`int main(void)` but it's trivial issue.  This is a codelite issue so remove the c tag?